# Order by alphanumeric in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can you help me?

my query is

```
SELECT num FROM sortnum ORDER BY lpad(num, 10, 0)
```

result of this query is not good 
here is the result

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
12 
13 
14 
1a 
2a 
2b 
A1 
A2 
A3 
A4 
B1 
A10 
A11 
B10
```

What is the best query for this type of data 
i want number first, then data starting with a , then with b

i want result like

```
1 
1a 
2 
2a 
2b 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
12 
13 
14 
A1 
A2 
A3 
A4 
A10 
A11 
B1 
B10
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that any alphabetic prefix will be at most one character in length, you could do:

```
SELECT   num
FROM     sortnum
ORDER BY
  CAST(num AS UNSIGNED)=0,     -- those starting with numbers before non-numbers
  CAST(num AS UNSIGNED),       -- then by number prefix (if any)
  LEFT(num,1),                 -- then by first character
  CAST(MID(num,2) AS UNSIGNED) -- then by remaining numbers
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78bfb/1/0).

Comment: Signed in just to say THANKS! This worked perfectly.

Comment: Your solution is the only one working on all mix of strings! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT num,
CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(num,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
FROM sortnum
ORDER BY num;
```